# How to add Interaction to the xdb contacts using xconnect provider of Data Exchange framework?

Tags: xdb, xconnect, data-exchange-framework

I have the requirement of add interactions to the xdb contacts. For that, I am using xconnect Provider. So how can I add Interactions by using the data exchange framework xconnect provider?

Comment: Try this "https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/xconnect-tutorial--4--search-contacts-and-interactions.html".

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, Is there any way to add interactions using value mapping set of data exchange framework in sitecore

Comment: Check this out - "https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-do-you-want-use-sitecore-provider-data-exchange-framework-chopra/".

Comment: Hi,i have checked out that.but i need to know how to use Interaction of default collection model in DEF or could you suggest me how to update interactions to xdb contacts using pipeline steps of DEF

Comment: Can you join Sitecore Community Slack? There you can contact @Maarten as he might have something for you.